# How to view an image in a popup using ASP.Net MVC with Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-ajax

I just want to know how to call upon a image using Ajax
for this I have my code below which will give you an idea of what I have used so far

**My .js File**

```
function loadData(Id) { 
   
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/FileManagement/GetId',
            data: { id: Id},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                alert(result.ManualContent),
                
                
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                debugger;
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
  
}
```

**My Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetId(int id)
        {
            IEnumerable<FileDetails> fileDetails = new List<FileDetails>();

            var file = (from a in _context.FileDetails.Where(m => m.Id == id)
                        select new
                        {
                            a.ManualContent,
                            a.Imagename
                        }).SingleOrDefault();


            return Json(file, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet );
        }
    }   
       }
```

**My View**

```
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">File List</h4>

                    <table class="table table-responsive-lg" id="tblFile">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Image</th>
                                <th>Keyword</th>
                                <th>Category Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="appendFile">

                            @foreach (var file in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="~/FileImage/@file.Imagename"
                                             class="rounded-circle"
                                             height="40" width="40"
                                             asp-append-version="true" id="Image" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>@file.Keyword</td>
                                    <td>@file.CategoriesName</td>
                                    <td><a href="#" class="preview-icon" onclick="loadData(@file.Id)">Read More...</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="Largecontent" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Largecontent" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="Largecontent"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal" id="divfile" role="dialog" style="display: none;overflow-y: scroll;">
        @*<div class="modal-backdrop"></div>*@
        <div class="modal-dialog dialog-box" style="width:96%">
            <div class="modal-content ">
                <div class="modal-header-small">
                    <i style="color:darkgreen; " class="fa fa-address-card-o"></i>&nbsp;File Content
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label id="txtid"></label>

                    <div id="audshow" style="display:none;"><audio src="" id="aud"></audio></div>
                    <div id="vidshow" style="display:none;"><video src="" id="vid"></video></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <div class="pull-left "></div>
                    @*<button id="btnSelect" class="btn btnsa " type="button" style='background-color:#62cb31'><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Continue</button>*@
                    <button id="btnCancels" class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @section styles{
        <link href="~/Scripts/plugins/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        @*<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.css">*@
        <style>
            .appadd {
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden !important;
                width: 180px !important;
                height: 30px !important;
                text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .hidetext {
                -webkit-text-security: rectangle; /* Default */
            }

            .topspace {
                margin-top: 10px !important;
            }

            .btn-mar-btm {
                margin-bottom: 10px !important;
            }

            .modal-backdrop {
                opacity: 0.4 !important;
            }

            @@media (min-width:900px) {
                .modal-dialog {
                    max-width: 700px !important;
                }
            }

            .modal-content {
                top: 20px;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .modal-footer {
                background-color: #f7f9fa;
            }

            .modal-header-small {
                padding: 12px 10px;
                background: #f7f9fa;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e5e7;
            }

            .col-mob {
                position: relative;
                width: 50%;
                min-height: 1px;
                padding-right: 15px;
                padding-left: 15px;
            }

            .mul {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                background-image: none;
                border: 1px solid #e5e6e7;
                border-radius: 1px;
                color: inherit;
                display: block;
                padding: 6px 12px;
                transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
                width: 100%;
                height: calc(2.25rem - 3px);
            }

            .time-bg1 {
                background-color: #FAF0E6 !important;
            }

            .time-bg2 {
                background-color: #e6f7ff !important;
            }

            .time-bg3 {
                background-color: #FFF5EE !important;
            }

            .time-bg4 {
                background-color: #F0FFF0 !important;
            }

            .time-bg5 {
                background-color: #cceeff !important;
            }

            textarea {
                overflow: hidden !important;
                resize: none !important;
            }

            .payment-card {
                border: 1px solid #e7eaec !important;
            }

            @@media only screen and (max-width : 767px) {
                .form-group {
                    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
                }

                .mar-btm {
                    margin-bottom: 16px !important;
                }
            }

            @@media only screen and (min-width : 961px) {
                .col-mob-tlbl {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 19%;
                    min-height: 1px;
                    padding-right: 15px;
                    padding-left: 15px;
                }

                .col-mob-time {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 27%;
                    min-height: 1px;
                    padding-right: 15px;
                    padding-left: 15px;
                }
            }

            @@media only screen and (max-width : 961px) {
                .col-mob-tlbl {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 19%;
                    min-height: 1px;
                    padding-right: 15px;
                    padding-left: 7px;
                }

                .col-mob-time {
                    position: relative;
                    width: 27%;
                    min-height: 1px;
                    padding-right: 9px;
                    padding-left: 15px;
                }

                .ws-change {
                    padding: 4px 0px !important;
                    font-size: 10px !important;
                }
            }

            .col-md-12 {
                padding-left: 0px !important;
                padding-right: 0px !important;
            }

            .breadcrumb-pad {
                padding-left: 17px !important;
            }
        </style>

    }
    @section scripts
                {

        <script src="~/FileList.js"></script>
    }
}
```

Can you guide me on what seems to be the problem to View the image file in the popup window. Since I can view only the `ManualContent` section and not the image with it

Comment: Do you NEED to do this using AJAX? This could be solved using a PartialViewResult

Comment: @JonathanOrtega Can you give me a sample example of how it can work?. Much appreciated